# Facing problem while running SQL Server SSIS 64 bit package for importing oracle data

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016

I am trying to import Oracle data in SQL Server, when running manually using IMPORT EXPORT Wizard 64 bit it's running successfully, but when trying from the SSIS package is throwing an error message, 32-bit oracle client already installed, Currently I am using Oracle 12c Oracle 64-bit client, SQL and window server also 64-bit, I tried to resolve this issue lot but no success.

I really need some help

[SSIS Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJgS0.png)

Comment: Did you try to run the package in 32 bit mode? That can generally be done by going to the properties of the SSIS Solution and setting Run64BitRuntime as false.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, I am using 12c 64-bit oracle client so 32-bit Import EXPORT will through error - 32bit ODBC driver will not support.

My issue fixed scheduled JOB for same SSIS package. its working fine now.

got help from below url -
https://www.intertech.com/running-ssis-packages-in-64-bit/

Thanks a lot for everyone.